# Unexpected commandButton behavior

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

The problem:
While the cursor is in the inputText and I press the "Enter" the dialog will popup
This is happen in Chrome but not via IE:

```
  <h:form id="mainForm" prependId="false">   
        <h:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13){}"/>
        <p:commandButton id="Button1" 
                         oncomplete="widgetVar.show()"/>
        <p:dialog id="Dialog1" 
                  widgetVar="widgetVar"
                  appendToBody="true"
                  dynamic="true"/>
    </h:form>
```

How can I prevent it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add `return false` to stop this event.
Like `onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13){return false;}"`